# C# .NET: load SQLite table to datagrid

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, datagrid

I am stuck.
I need to load table from SQLite database to list, and use it as itemsource for datagrid once window loads. But in my case datagrid remains empty.

Class:

```
public class Requests
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Kind{ get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
}
```

App:

```
private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Requests> admrequests = new List<Requests>();
            string db_path = @"URI=file:D:\Foo\Bar\Agenda.db";
            using var con = new SQLiteConnection(db_path);
            con.Open();
            string select = "SELECT * FROM accreq WHERE pzstate=1";
            using var command = new SQLiteCommand(select, con);
            using SQLiteDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                admrequests.Add(new Requests() { Id = rdr.GetInt32(0), Username = rdr.GetString(1), Kind = rdr.GetString(2), Database = rdr.GetString(3), Date = rdr.GetInt32(4) });
            }

            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
            dgr_unsolved.ItemsSource = admrequests ;
```

Everything is in main window class ( eg: *public partial class Window_admin : Window*)

SQL query works in external DBEditor app and paths are correct.
I don't really see where is a mistake. Any help would be very appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a break point to see if data is coming back? It would be helpful to share what your grid looks like. Is this win forms or web forms?

Comment: I just tried to recreate this piece of app (two plain WPF windows, button on first one and grid on second) on my home computer and i works normally. It seems, that I am digging at wrong part of code. Thank you for pointing me to idea, that code itself may not be a problem. I will report result of your other ideas as soon as i got to work.